# Tkinter install in Python version 3.2

Tags: python, tkinter

After researching a little I found some libraries like pygame, tkinter, etc. I was able to install pygame easily but am not able to find any help on how to install tkinter for v3.2.

I know many of these type of q's heve been answered but most of them show only errors when importing Python or it is for Linux/mac.

I have a Windows based os.

Comment: `tkinter` should be installed automatically with python. Try `import tkinter` (lowercase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter is already installed with Python so you just need to `import tkinter`. Don't import `Tkinter` as you might see in some tutorials because Python 3+ has a different version.